# Synthesize speech on Windows 10: Scenario_SynthesizeText.xaml.h is missing

Tags: c++, windows, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have some experience with JS, Python, Go, but for the first time I need to accomplish something with C++. I can try to get synthesized audio with C# but I think it is better to absorb knowledge about more generic technology. I follow [this documentation page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.media.speechsynthesis.speechsynthesizer). From [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis/cpp/Scenario_SynthesizeText.xaml.cpp) I found that I need to include `Scenario_SynthesizeText.xaml.h`.

In my official Windows 10 Virtualbox image I installed Visual Studio Build Tools 2019 plus Universal Windows Platform build tools.

My code:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "Scenario_SynthesizeText.xaml.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello World\n";

    InitializeComponent();
    synth = std::ref new SpeechSynthesizer();
    media = std::ref new MediaElement();

    return 0;
}
```

But compilation is failed on Windows 10:

```
D:\>cl __windowsTTSTest.cc

fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'Scenario_SynthesizeText.xaml.h': No such file or directory
```

Looks like I need to install some dependency?

Answer (score 0):

Put to the same directory this file from https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/fe8567faf2efdea3672c2ba642ba7b925ff6467e/Samples/SpeechRecognitionAndSynthesis/cpp/Scenario_SynthesizeText.xaml.h